# How to ask authorization to access photos / camera roll with custom view?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, photosframework

How do I create a custom view that will override the "alert view" showing when the app asks for access to camera roll/ photos album? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the message displayed to the user in the alertView. You can use  `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`.

Add this key to your info.plist and set your custom message as the value.

> **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription**
>
> Specifies the reason for accessing the user’s photo library. See
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription for details.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom view to ask authorization is not possible.

The only change you could do is to specify reason for accessing the user's photo library. (gabbler's answer)

With this, I decided to just create a custom view with a button asking the user to allow access to camera roll. The button can call a method to assetslibrary to send a user prompt on access.

This is more of making things smooth for the user. 
See Hyperlapse onboarding, its awesome!